# Println the return values of an executable

Tags: java, executable

I have deploy an matlab .m file into an windows console application. The matlab file that I deploy is in fact a matlab function which have no arguments and return a list of integer. I am running that .exe from java code using process to run my executable file. I am tried to read the return values using the following code:

```
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("epidemic.exe");
            //process.waitFor();
            System.out.println("....");

            InputStream in = process.getInputStream();  // To read process standard output
            InputStream err = process.getErrorStream(); // To read process error output

            while (process.isAlive()) {
                while (in.available() > 0 || err.available() > 0) {
                    if (in.available() > 0) {
                        System.out.print((char)in.read()); // You might wanna echo it to your console to see progress
                    }
                    if (err.available() > 0) {
                        err.read(); // You might wanna echo it to your console to see progress
                    }
                }

                Thread.sleep(1);
            }


           System.out.println("....");
```

EDIT: Based on the proposed changes I re-change my code. Again, it doesn't seem print the returned values. If this code is ok, how could I check if the executable indeed return values?

Comment: Are you using javaw or java executable to run it? javaw will hide the console window.

Comment: Is the `epidemic.exe` actually returning anything? Are you closing the `Reader`? Are there any `Exception`s thrown?

Comment: @ESP how can I check what I am using in order to run the exe? Mera no I got no exceptions it seems that while loop doesnlt operate. Epidemic.exe is deployed from matlab using compile application is a function which returns a vector of integers.

Comment: How are you running your Java code?

Comment: I am running my java code from  Netbeans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `while` loop tries to read *whole lines* from the *standard output* of the started process.

I highlighted the potential problems. If the process does not write a whole line, or it writes to its standard error for example, `reader.readLine()` will block forever.

Also note that a process has 2 output streams: standard output and standard error. Both has a buffer, and if any of them gets filled without you reading it, the process will be blocked when trying to write more outputs.

To ensure the process does not get blocked, you have to read both of its output streams, here is an example how to do it:

```
InputStream in = process.getInputStream();  // To read process standard output
InputStream err = process.getErrorStream(); // To read process error output

while (proc.isAlive()) {
    while (in.available() > 0 || err.available() > 0) {
        if (in.available() > 0)
            in.read(); // You might wanna echo it to your console to see progress

        if (err.available() > 0)
            err.read(); // You might wanna echo it to your console to see progress
    }

    Thread.sleep(1);
}
```

If you want to print the data read from the output streams of the process, you can do it like this:

```
System.out.print((char)in.read()); // read() returns int, convert it to char
```

Comment: In order to check the returned values, I just have to println in.read()?

Comment: @JoseRamon Just print it as a char, e.g. `System.out.print((char)in.read());`.

Comment: Hmm it doesn't print anything.

Comment: @JoseRamon Then there is a good chance your process does not output anything. Try to run it from a command line first (not from Java).

Comment: You should read both `in` and `err` at the same time or you may end up blocked.

Comment: How can I output in terminal the returned values?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Note that I only read if `available()` returns a positive value which means subsequent `read()` will not block.

Comment: @JoseRamon Edited my answer, see at the end how a character returned by `read()` can be printed to the console.

Comment: @icza - Yes but both buffers are limited - if app prints a constant stream to stdout keeping you spinning reading `in` and never reading from `err` you might never read from stderr - which could then fill and block. It is a rare situation.

Comment: Yes I already tried and I couldn't manage to print the output.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Yes, that is a very rare case. But nonetheless I updated the code to avoid that case too.